# Android.mk NDK/JNI: Cannot link dependency .aar

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm building a library for Android called "rnmultithreading" that contains native code (C++). The native code depends on another library called "reanimated", which I am including in the C++ code.

Both of those libraries are NOT distributed through maven but instead installed locally. reanimated is packaged as a prebuilt `.aar`. I want to do the same, unless it's absolutely not possible.

Now I don't want to compile reanimated into my library, since then the user cannot upgrade reanimated without me having to rebuild my library.

I'm working on all of this [in this PR](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-multithreading/pull/5/files), which also includes the `Android.mk` files. I don't want to paste the contents of all my build files here, since that's a lot of lines. But here are the links to those files:

- [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-multithreading/blob/android-mk/android/build.gradle)
- [`JNI/Android.mk`](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-multithreading/blob/android-mk/android/src/main/JNI/Android.mk)
- [`JNI/Application.mk`](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-multithreading/blob/android-mk/android/src/main/JNI/Application.mk)
- [`JNI/react/Android.mk`](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-multithreading/blob/android-mk/android/src/main/JNI/react/Android.mk)

When I try to build this thing using `./gradlew assembleDebug`, I get a build error:

```
> Task :buildRnMultithreading FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildRnMultithreading'.
> Process 'command '/Users/mrousavy/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 57s
12 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 6 up-to-date
```

a few lines above that, the actual linker error:

```
[x86_64] SharedLibrary  : librnmultithreading.so
make: Leaving directory '/Users/mrousavy/Projects/react-native-multithreading/android/src/main/JNI'
fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
./../cpp/cpp-adapter.cpp:23: error: undefined reference to 'mrousavy::multithreading::install(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, std::__ndk1::function<std::__ndk1::shared_ptr<reanimated::Scheduler> ()>, std::__ndk1::function<std::__ndk1::shared_ptr<reanimated::ErrorHandler> (std::__ndk1::shared_ptr<reanimated::Scheduler>)>)'
./../Common/MakeJSIRuntime.cpp:38: error: undefined reference to 'facebook::jsc::makeJSCRuntime()'
./../Common/RNMultithreadingInstaller.cpp:36: error: undefined reference to 'reanimated::RuntimeDecorator::decorateRuntime(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >)'
./../Common/RNMultithreadingInstaller.cpp:55: error: undefined reference to 'reanimated::ShareableValue::adapt(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, reanimated::RuntimeManager*, reanimated::ValueType)'
./../Common/RNMultithreadingInstaller.cpp:78: error: undefined reference to 'reanimated::ShareableValue::getValue(facebook::jsi::Runtime&)'
./../Common/RNMultithreadingInstaller.cpp:81: error: undefined reference to 'reanimated::ShareableValue::adapt(facebook::jsi::Runtime&, facebook::jsi::Value const&, reanimated::RuntimeManager*, reanimated::ValueType)'
./../Common/RNMultithreadingInstaller.cpp:65: error: undefined reference to 'reanimated::Scheduler::scheduleOnJS(std::__ndk1::function<void ()>)'
./../Common/RNMultithreadingInstaller.cpp:70: error: undefined reference to 'reanimated::Scheduler::scheduleOnJS(std::__ndk1::function<void ()>)'
./../Common/RNMultithreadingInstaller.cpp:66: error: undefined reference to 'reanimated::ShareableValue::getValue(facebook::jsi::Runtime&)'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [/Users/mrousavy/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.1.6352462/build/core/build-binary.mk:725: /Users/mrousavy/Projects/react-native-multithreading/android/build/tmp/buildRnMultithreading/local/x86_64/librnmultithreading.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
make: Entering directory '/Users/mrousavy/Projects/react-native-multithreading/android/src/main/JNI'
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libreactnativejni.so
make: Leaving directory '/Users/mrousavy/Projects/react-native-multithreading/android/src/main/JNI'
fcntl(): Bad file descriptor
```

I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong, since it does successfully extract the libreanimated.so from the .aar:

[image]

does anybody have an idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Libraries in jnilibs aren't something you can use as a build dependency. They are only for loading directly via JNI. If you want to use them from your native code you need to follow https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4.1-prefab-publish